# how to align controls left, right and center in relative layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have 3 controls which I want one aligned left, the other centered, and the last all the way to the right in a relative layout.

I have tried that with the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backimg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logoimg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/closebtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/close"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>



    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

This stacks all of the controls on top of each other.

How can I get this to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the imageViews width to wrap_content and everything will be as you want 
here is your new code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/closebtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/close"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>



<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:layout_toRightOf` to tell the view to be to the right of another

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backimg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logoimg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/backimg"  
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/closebtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/close"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logoimg"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>



    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:id="@+id/logoimg" <- and here->android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logoing" the id isn't the same

Comment: No, I did not  try it

Comment: so you have just one typing mistake

Comment: Yes. Thank you for noticing.. Fixed